# Web service runs but database record does not get inserted

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a C# asmx web service that is being called, and I am seeing the results come back on the client, so I know that the code is running to completion without throwing any exceptions.  Here is the web service class:

```
namespace App_WebRole
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SubscriptionStatus
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SubscriptionStatus : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            DataSet1 dataSet = new DataSet1();
            DataSet1TableAdapters.StatusRequestsTableAdapter statusTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.StatusRequestsTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.StatusRequestsRow newRow = dataSet.StatusRequests.NewStatusRequestsRow();
            newRow.ApplicationID = "Test";
            newRow.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
            dataSet.StatusRequests.Rows.Add(newRow);
            dataSet.StatusRequests.AcceptChanges();
            statusTableAdapter.Update(dataSet);
            return "Hello World 2";
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this locally on my machine with a local SQL Server Express database, and I do not see any records being inserted in to the appropriate table.

If I change the return value, I do see the changed value in the client. Also, I looked at the web.config file in the local web site directory, and it has the connection string for the local SQL Server Express database.

Comment: The problem with not updating probably lies within the Method     DataSet1TableAdapters.StatusRequestsTableAdapter.Update(), but without being able to see this code it is impossible to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, to get this working, I switched away from using a DataSet (.xsd) in my application to using LINQ to SQL classes (.dbml) instead. James' answer may in fact have done the trick, but by the time he posted it, I had already switched it over to the dbml and had it working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting changes before update will cause update not to see anything that needs updating. Remove the `dataSet.StatusRequests.AcceptChanges();` line. Update will accept the changes for you once it has completed.